# To draw the graph or explain why the relationship cannot be represented by a graph.

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, graph-theory, relations

To either draw the graph or explain why the relationship cannot be represented by a graph:

(a) The set $V = \{1,2,...,9\}$ and the relationship $x ∼ y$ when $x−y$ is a non-zero multiple of $3$.

(b) The set $V = \{1,2,...,9\}$  and the relationship $x ∼ y$ when $y$ is a multiple of $x$.

(c) The set $V = \{1,2,...,9\}$  and the relationship $x ∼ y$ when $0 < |x−y| < 3$.

---

According to me (a) and (c) will be a graph and (b) will not be a graph.

We know a relation is a graph when it is irreflexive and symmetric. (b) will not be a graph since $x$ is a multiple of $x$ and the relation becomes reflexive.

I did not consider (b) to be a graph as I was considering only simple graphs, with no loops or multi-edges.

---

The following are the images of the graphs:
[image]

Is the solution correct?

Answer (score 1):

All can be represented (so long as we permit a *directed* graph for part b):

a)

[image]

b)

[image]

c)

[image]

Comment: In part (c) 1 and 2 , 3 and 4 ,... like these are also adjacent

Comment: $0<|x-y|<3$ i.e. $|x-y|=1,2$

Comment: I did not consider (b) to be a graph as I was considering only simple graphs, with no loops or multi-edges.

Comment: The observation here should be that (b) needs a *directed graph* to be properly represented.

Comment: @Christoph what is your point of view for (c)?